# How to check if some categorical variables are within a column in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to write an `if statement` that checks if one OR another categorical variable is within a column in my dataframe. Therefore, I am using `%in%`. It works perfectly fine when I have 1 variable:

```
if("setosa" %in% iris$Species){
  print("hi")
}
[1] "hi"
```

But I cannot use it if I have a condition `OR`.

```
# it should return TRUE because "setosa" is within the column Species
if(("setosa" | "new") %in% iris$Species){
  print("hi")
}

Error in "setosa" | "virginica" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Does anybody know how to do it or if I can use another function to check if my `if statement` is TRUE or FALSE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `any(c("setosa","new") %in% iris$Species)`.

Comment: @pluke `c("setosa","new")` gives me this error: `Error in if (c("setosa", "new") %in% iris$Species) { :  the condition has length > 1`

But if I use `any` as @user2974951 has said, it works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the conditions in a vector and check if any is true (for OR, use `all` for AND) `any(c("setosa","new") %in% iris$Species)`.